# Convert all relative imports to absolute automatically in python

Tags: python, import

I am trying to structure my *python 2.7* project (which entails several subdirectories) correctly. 
I have added *__init__.py* files on every level, and in the case of imports it seems that the *"best" practice* is to use **absolute** imports of the sort:

```
import top_package_folder.package_subfolder.module_name
```

instead of:

```
import .module_name
```

even when my code lives in the package_subfolder directory.

As I learned about this recently, I am now looking for a way to automatically convert all those relative imports to absolute ones.

*(I tried autopep8 and could not manage to make imports absolute.)*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it's best to use absolute imports?

Comment: @martineau,thats a good question. I reached this conclusion after an online search, which suggested that up to a point absolute imports were "kind of mandatory" for projects run as packages, until after python 2.5 when Guido mentioned its not any more, but nevertheless implied relative imports are still useful only in particular cases (but did not elaborate any more on that).

Comment: btw, best answer on relative imports ever:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/3607939

Comment: you'll find most python devs prefer the `from top_package.sub_package import module_name` style. `import top_package_folder.package_subfolder.module_name` makes your code fantastically verbose

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `absolufy-imports` https://github.com/MarcoGorelli/absolufy-imports :

### Installation

```
pip install absolufy-imports
```

### Usage as a pre-commit hook

See [pre-commit](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit) for instructions

Sample `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/MarcoGorelli/absolufy-imports
    rev: v0.3.1
    hooks:
    -   id: absolufy-imports
```

### Command-line example

```
$ cat mypackage/myfile.py
from . import __version__

$ absolufy-imports mypackage/myfile.py

$ cat mypackage/myfile.py
from mypackage import __version__
```

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this little package